# extjs validator scope

Tags: extjs, extjs4, validation

How do I define texfield validator scope?
I define validator in controller with this code:

```
this.editView.getRegNumberTextField().validator  = this.regNumberValidator;
//...
regNumberValidator:function (input) {
//validation here
}
```

But in this case the scope  in regNumberValidator function is RegNumberTextField. I want it to be the Controller scope. I tried Ext.apply with {scope:this} but it didn't help. There should be some way to define the scope, like in `on('event',handler, scope)` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem is Ext.bind
The code is:

```
this.editView.getRegNumberTextField().validator = Ext.bind(this.regNumberValidator,this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply define 'controller' field attribute, as your controller, and then you will have access to controller scope within validator with this.getController():

```
xtype: 'combo',
controller: 'mycontrolleralias',
validator :  function () {
    return this.getValue() === this.getController().getViewModel().get('record').getId()?
                                        'Affiliate cannot be the parent of itself':true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to create a delegate:

```
this.editView.getRegNumberTextField().validator = this.regNumberValidator.createDelegate(this);

//...

regNumberValidator:function (input) {
//validation here
}
```